# iPhone not displaying top of web page when viewed on a smartphone

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

I have been developing a reactive design for a web page. When viewed on a desk top the whole page displays (with browser window shrunk down to phone size), but when viewed with an iPhone (and does same on Android) the top 100'ish pixels are off the top of the page. Has anyone come across this issue?

My code and CSS are below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Tin_Mouse_size.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->

// When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Images/Roll_Overs_Home_On.png','Images/Roll_Overs_Me_On.png','Images/Roll_Overs_Work_On.png','Images/Roll_Overs_Contact_On.png')">

<div id="centeredcontent">

  <div id="blank"></div>

<div id="home">
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','Images/Roll_Overs_Home_On.png',1)"><img src="Images/Roll_Overs_Home_Off.png" alt="Home" name="Image1" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Image1" /></a>
</div>

<div id="me">
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','Images/Roll_Overs_Me_On.png',1)"><img src="Images/Roll_Overs_Me_Off.png" alt="Me" name="Image2" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Image2" /></a>
</div>

<div id="work">
  <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image3','','Images/Roll_Overs_Work_On.png',1)"><img src="Images/Roll_Overs_Work_Off.png" alt="Work" name="Image3" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Image3" /></a>
</div>

<div id="contact">
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image4','','Images/Roll_Overs_Contact_On.png',1)"><img src="Images/Roll_Overs_Contact_Off.png" alt="Contact" name="Image4" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Image4" /></a>
</div>

<div class="Contact_Holder_Div">

<div class="Designed_In_Cornwall"><a href="mailto:info@dandcauctions.co.uk" title="Email Us" class="designed_in_cornwall_button"></a></div>

<div class="Email"><a title='Click Me and send an email' href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Email','','Images/mail-square.png',1)"><img src="Images/mail.png" alt="Email" name="Email" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Email" /></a></div>

<div class="gtalk"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Google Talk','','Images/gtalk-square.png',1)"><img src="Images/gtalk.png" alt="Google Talk" title="Google Talk" name="Google Talk" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Google Talk" /></a></div>

<div class="linkedin"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('LinkedIn','','Images/linkedin-logo-square.png',1)"><img src="Images/linkedin-logo.png" alt="LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn" name="LinkedIn" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="LinkedIn" /></a></div>

<div class="twitter"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','Images/twitter-square.png',1)"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" name="Twitter" title="Twitter" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Twitter" /></a></div>

<div class="flickr"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Flickr','','Images/flickr-square.png',1)"><img src="Images/flickr.png" alt="Flickr" title="Flickr" name="Flickr" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="Flickr" /></a></div>
</div>

</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
    /* Defaults / Desktop View */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#centeredcontent {
    width: 480px;
    height: 640px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -240px;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
h1 { color: #000000; }

h2 { color: #000000; } 

h3 { color: #000000; }

h4 { color: #000000; }

@media only screen and (min-width:980px ) and (max-width:2880px) {
    /*Large Desktop*/
    #centeredcontent {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
#blank {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background-color:#FFF
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #home {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 84px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 242px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #contact {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 558px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #home-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 84px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 242px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #contact-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 558px;
    top: 0px;
}

div#box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 160px;}

#thumbBox{ /*Outermost DIV for thumbnail viewer*/
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto;
padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
background: #FFFFFF;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 10;
cursor: hand;
cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbBox .footerbar{ /*Footer DIV of thumbbox that contains "close" link */
font: bold 16px Tahoma;
letter-spacing: 5px;
line-height: 1.1em;
color: black;
padding: 5px 0;
text-align: right;
}

#thumbLoading{ /*DIV for showing "loading" status while thumbbox is being generated*/
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #EFEFEF;
padding: 5px;
z-index: 5;
}

}
@media only screen and (min-width:651px ) and (max-width:979px) {
    /*Small Desktop / Large Tablet View*/
    #centeredcontent {
    width: 650px;
    height: 640px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -325px;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
#blank {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background-color:#FFF
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #home {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 167px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 325px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #contact {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 483px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #home-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 167px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 325px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #contact-work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 483px;
    top: 0px;
}

div#box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 160px;}

#thumbBox{ /*Outermost DIV for thumbnail viewer*/
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto;
padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
background: #FFFFFF;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 10;
cursor: hand;
cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbBox .footerbar{ /*Footer DIV of thumbbox that contains "close" link */
font: bold 16px Tahoma;
letter-spacing: 5px;
line-height: 1.1em;
color: black;
padding: 5px 0;
text-align: right;
}

#thumbLoading{ /*DIV for showing "loading" status while thumbbox is being generated*/
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #EFEFEF;
padding: 5px;
z-index: 5;
}

}
@media only screen and (min-width:480px ) and (max-width:650px) {
    /* Small Tablet View */
    #centeredcontent {
    width: 480px;
    height: 640px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -240px;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
    #blank {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background-color:#FFF
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #home {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 82px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 240px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 82px;
    top: 158px;
}
    #contact {
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 240px;
    top: 158px;
}
    #home-work {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me-work {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work-work {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 240px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #contact-work {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 360px;
    top: 0px;
}

div#box {
    width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 130px;}

#thumbBox{ /*Outermost DIV for thumbnail viewer*/
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto;
padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
background: #FFFFFF;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 10;
cursor: hand;
cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbBox .footerbar{ /*Footer DIV of thumbbox that contains "close" link */
font: bold 16px Tahoma;
letter-spacing: 5px;
line-height: 1.1em;
color: black;
padding: 5px 0;
text-align: right;
}

#thumbLoading{ /*DIV for showing "loading" status while thumbbox is being generated*/
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #EFEFEF;
padding: 5px;
z-index: 5;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
    /* Smartphone view*/
    #centeredcontent {
    width: 320px;
    height: 640px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
 #blank {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background-color:#FFF
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #home {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 20px;
}
    #me {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 160px;
}
    #work {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 300px;
}
    #contact {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 440px;
}
    #home-work {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #me-work {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #work-work {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #contact-work {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 240px;
    top: 0px;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your website so I can see it in action?

Comment: You should not use old Dreamweaver WYSIWYG editing to create sites that should work on modern platforms. All that `MM_` bullshit in there is unnecessary and potentially troublesome legacy cluttering, and automatically generated by old versions of Dreamweaver (from when it was still Macromedia, hence the MM_ prefix).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here (clipped to relevant parts):

```
#centeredcontent {
    height: 640px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
```

iPhone screens are historically 320x480 pixels. When retina screens were introduced by the iPhone 4, this doubled both ways to 640x960, but to prevent this from making sites unreadable small if they specify pixel sizes, the old resolutions were maintained and the content just blown up. Hence an iPhone 4/4S still considers itself a 320x480 browser. Android browsers have since done the same with high resolution screens.

On this 480 pixels high iPhone screen, you are then positioning the content at 240 pixels down (`top:50%`) and up 320 pixels (`margin-top:-320px`). Hence you're moving your content 80 pixels beyond the top edge of the browser, maybe a tad more due to the address bar taking up space too.

Bottom line: don't vertically center content, it's a bad idea without ensuring it will fit. Your final media query for small screens should not attempt to center but just let smartphone browser scaling do its job.

Comment: Thanks Niels, that will be a big help.